# Drop rows of a pandas dataFrame with unique elements in a given column. (by unique I mean repeated once)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, unique

Let's say I have the following dataFrame and I want to drop the rows containing 10, and 100, i.e. the elements that have appeared only once in col1.

[image: DataFrame]

I can do the following:

```
a = df.groupby('col1').size()
b = list(a[a == 1].index)
```

and then have a for loop and drop the rows one by one:

```
d_ind = df[df['col1']==b[0]].index
df.drop(d_ind, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Is there any faster, more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `duplicated` method on `col1`, which can detect whether an element has duplicates with `keep=False` parameter and returns a boolean Series which you can use to *subset/filter/drop* rows:

```
df[df.col1.duplicated(keep=False)]

#   col1  col2  months
#0     1     3       6
#1     1     4       6
#4     4    20       6
#5     4    11       7
#6     4    12       7
```